# What would happen to a werewolf stuck in between transformation?

Tags: biology, supernatural

The coming of age in a group of werewolves is the first transformation. Some will transform properly and some will die in the process. However there are some who get stuck in between their human and wolf form and are unable to change back. This can also occur if they attempt to reverse their lycanthropy with tainted wolfsbane. Those stuck in between are usually banished from the pack to fend for themselves, as they will bring unnecessary danger of discovery.

However, I've come to doubt that those stuck in between could even survive. I have reason to believe that they'd simply drop dead after a few hours in such an extreme condition, if not killed off by predators. Would it be possible for them to live, even if they are severely disabled? Or are the differences between the biology of wolves and humans so different that they would die?

Comment: I should think this would be bad, not unlike a [Star Trek transporter accident](https://youtu.be/Ro_QpDJX-Sk?t=40s).  After all, things on the inside are all skewompus as wolf vs. human organ placement is not close enough, and that's assuming the organs are viable half-way between their change.  Yikes.

Comment: This heavily depends on the anatomy of the hybrid form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how anatomically identical you need your human and wolf forms to be.

If you need a dead werewolf in human form to appear totally human even under surgical dissection; and if you need a dead wolf form werewolf to be similarly indistinguishable from a normal wolf, then organs need to move during the transformation.   Which means that anyone stuck halfway between the two forms will have a pretty hard time of it, biologically.

If however, you only need the werewolves to appear human or lupine on the outside, then their organ locations can remain relatively stationary during transformation.  When in human form, they might have to carry a little extra body fat to cover up the weird shape of their stomach and chest, but in a culture which accepts baggy clothing, they could pass casual inspection.

In such a world, a half-transformed man-wolf would still stand out, requiring either banishment or death; but if they can avoid the claws and teeth of their former pack mates, they should be able to survive biologically, despite their odd form.

Answer (score 3):

Depending *at what point* in the transformation they get stuck they'll either die fast or slow, mainly depending on organ and limb "development" within the hybrid form. Most hybrids are going to be non-viable, caught with vital organs, (lungs, heart, brain), in mid-transition; others will be maladaptive with limbs that are either entirely non-functional or that work very poorly. The "luckiest" ones will survive physically but waste slowly without a pack and the social structure that their human and wolf natures demand.